# Inicializar objeto no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho uma classe `Cidade` que tem a propriedade `Estado` do tipo `Estado`:

```
public class Cidade
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Nome é obrigatório!")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Estado é obrigatório!")]
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }

    public Cidade() { }

    public Cidade(int ID, String Nome, Estado Estado)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Nome = Nome;
        this.Estado = Estado;
    }
```

Quando vou cadastrar uma nova `Cidade` dá erro de referência nula. Acho que é porque o objeto `Estado` não foi inicializado, mas onde eu devo inicializar esse objeto? já tentei no construtor da classe `Cidade`, mas não deu certo.

Segue o método no `controller` que recebe o objeto `Cidade` da `View` para o cadastro.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult AddCidade(Cidade cidade)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                CidadeDal cd = new CidadeDal();
                cd.Salvar(cidade);
                return RedirectToAction("AddCidade");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Houve um problema ao preencher o formulário, verifique os erros e tente novamente!");
                return RedirectToAction("AddCidade");
            }
        }
```

Segue a View:

```
@model Projeto_P1.Models.Cidade
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro de Cidades";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddCidade", "Cidade", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Ocorreram erros no preenchimento das informações, verifique a lista abaixo e corrija os erros!")
    <div class="container">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Cidade")
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "maiusculo"})
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("País")
                @Html.DropDownList("pais", (SelectList)ViewData["paises"], "Selecione", new { id = "PaisID"})
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.Label("Estado")
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Estado, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Selecione")
            </div>

            <br />

            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PaisID").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Estado/ListaEstados",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { ID: $(this).val() },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var elements = "";
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        elements = elements + '<option value="' + this.ID + '">' + this.Nome + '</option>'
                    })
                    $('#Estado').empty().attr('disabled', false).append(elements);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Coloque o código onde você chama o construtor de Cidade.

Comment: coloca em cima da sua classe
[Seriazable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua modelagem está incorreta. Do jeito que é feita, o `ModelBinder` (classe que converte os valores da `View` no parâmetro passado para o `Controller`) não consegue fazer a associação corretamente, porque `Estado` é uma entidade complexa, e o que está sendo colocando em tela é apenas o Id do `Estado`, que é uma entidade mais simples. No caso, um inteiro.

Modifique seu `Model` para o seguinte:

```
public class Cidade
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Estado é obrigatório!")]
    public int EstadoID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Nome é obrigatório!")]
    public String Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Pode parecer prolixo ter `EstadoID` e o objeto `virtual Estado` em separado, mas na verdade é assim que o Entity Framework e o MVC funcionam. Imagine que você não quer utilizar as informações do `Estado`, ou seja, carregá-lo minimamente. A única informação necessária para isso é o Id do `Estado`.

Os construtores não são realmente necessários pro que você precisa fazer. Usando o inicializador de objetos que o @DiegoZanardo colocou na resposta dele, você já consegue inicializar qualquer objeto.

Por fim, na `View`, modifique o seguinte:

```
        <div>
            @Html.Label("País")
            @Html.DropDownList("pais", (SelectList)ViewData["paises"], "Selecione", new { id = "PaisID"})
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Label("EstadoID")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EstadoID, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Selecione")
        </div>
```

Isto fará a correlação entre a variável inteira do `Model` e a `DropDownList`.

Comment: Cigano obrigado, hoje não vou poder fazer o teste, mas vou fazer amanhã e depois posto aqui o resultado.

Comment: Essa abordagem deu certo, muito obrigado, realmente é estranho trabalhar com a propriedade do tipo complexa e outra propriedade representando o ID dessa mesma propriedade, mas funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que sua classe `Estado` seja a seguinte:

```
public class Estado
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Para usar o construtor da classe `Cidade`, você teria que fazer o seguinte:

```
var estado = new Estado()
{
    ID = 1,
    Nome = "SP"
}
var cidade = new Cidade(1, "São Paulo", estado);
```

Comment: Diego me desculpe mas não entendi muito bem, você fala pra eu criar o objeto  estado na classe Cidade quando eu fizer o submit no formulário o Asp.Net vai utilizar esse construtor para montar o objeto estado dentro de cidade: outra coisa no exemplo acima você criou o contrutor e colocou os dado ID = 1 Nome = São Paulo, esses dados virão da View, como fica pra eu montar isso de forma dinâmica, para que os dados digitados no fomulários sejam usados nesse objeto?

Comment: @user3670112, coloca sua view e seu controller, o que você fez até o momento, assim consigo fazer um exemplo melhor.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta e postei lá.